# Scrapy - how to parse multiple start_urls

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy

I am working on my first scrapy project and starting with a fairly simple website stockx.

I would like to scrape the different categories of items. If I use the below URLs as my start_urls. How do I parse through each start URL?

> https://stockx.com/sneakers',https://stockx.com/streetwear',https://stockx.com/collectibles',
>   https://stockx.com/handbags',https://stockx.com/watches

The product page is typically structured as the following:

> https://stockx.com/air-max-90-patta-homegrown-grass

I am trying to read through the documentation on this topic but couldn't quite follow it.

I know the below isn't right because I'm forcing a list of result URLs, just not sure how the multiple start_urls should be processed in the first parse.

```
   def parse(self, response):

        #obtain number of pages per product category 
        text = list(map(lambda x: x.split('='), 
    response.xpath('//a[@class="PagingButton__PaginationButton-sc-1o2t560- 
    0 eZnUxt"]/@href').extract()))
    total_pages = int(text[-1][-1])
    #compile a list of URLs for each result page 
    cat =['sneakers','streetwear','collectibles','handbags','watches']   
    cat = ['https://stockx.com/{}'.format(x) for x in cat]

    lst=[]

    for x in cat:
        for y in range (1,total_pages+1):
            result_urls=lst.append(x+'?page={}'.format(y))

    for url in result_urls[7:9]:
    # print('Lets try: ', url)
        yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_results)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this -

```
class ctSpider(Spider):
name = "stack"
    def start_requests(self):
        for d in [URLS]:
            yield Request(d,callback=self.parse)
...
```

Comment: This is essentially the default implementation of `start_requests` so it's easier to just use `self.start_urls` as @Backtrack

Comment: I see the main benefit of using `start_requests` to explicitly control requests params like headers, method

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is use using `start_urls` : https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.4/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_urls

```
class MLBoddsSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "stockx.com"
   allowed_domains = ["stockx.com"]
   start_urls = [
       "https://stockx.com/watches",
       "https://stockx.com/collectibles",

   ]

   def parse(self, response):
         ................
         ........
```

you can even control the `start_requests`.

Comment: I read the documentation and still a bit confused. 1) do I need to use allowed_domains rather than allowed_urls when I have multiple urls? 2)how should i go about constructing the result pages?  Wach result page has the following format the following https://stockx.com/streetwear?page=3   how do I direct the first parse so it knows it's parsing all the streetwear result pages from the https://stockx.com/streetwear start_url and not the other ones?  thank you very much for your help!

Comment: use allowed domains. you can use link extractor based approach  to crawl pagination. stockx.com/streetwear?page=3 and other pages

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension in place of the initial start_urls list. For instance...

```
class myScraper(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'movies'  
  abc = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
  url= "amazon.com/movies/{x}"
  start_urls = [url.format(x) for x in abc]
```

**Note**: Please don't run this, this was just for inspiration purposes. I did something like this in a project a while back(and was too lazy look it up again) and it worked. It saves you the time of having to create a custom start_requests function.

The url I used ***does not exist*** its just an example of something you can do.

The main idea here ***is to use a list comprehension in place of the default start_urls list*** so that you dont have to make a fancy function.